# Cannot add System.Data.Spatial to my Domain classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, shared-libraries

I have an application that use `EF5`. I have a library project with my domian classes.
I want to have use `DbGeaography` in one of my classes but I cannot add the `System.Data.Spatial` reference to my project. It does not appear on the Assemblies.  I checked that my library is on .Net 4.5 and it is using that Framework.

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13910685/609176) specifies that DbGeography is in `System.Data.Entity` in EF5. Try that?

Comment: Thank you I added EntityFramework to the class library from Manage Nuget Packages and System.Data.Spatial and it is working now.

Comment: Note that in EF6, this has been renamed System.Data.Entity.Spatial, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469466

Comment: Why the hell would you want this. Im actually looking for a workaround in where I dont use some DB ORM specific type on a model property.. What you want is IMO bad practice

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Always Check that Entity framework is installed to used `System.Data.Spatial`. Also, add in your class:

```
using System.Data.Spatial;
```

Update: in EF6 this has been renamed to `System.Data.Entity.Spatial`

Comment: Thank you I did that and it works but is good to have it as answer so another people can benefit from this post

Comment: It was the renamed to System.Data.Entity.Spatial that did it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Spatial worked for me..Thanks alot..Upvoted

Comment: perfect answer .